# What are the individual segments in a version number called?

Tags: versioning, semantics

The following version number `4.10.9.7` is segmented into four pieces. What is the word for one of those segments? If one was to use it in a sentence, one might say,

> A version number is comprised of one or more ___

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Semver

The most common term comes from the semver spec, which uses *identifier*:

> Precedence for two pre-release versions with the same major, minor, and patch version MUST be determined by comparing each dot separated **identifier** from left to right until a difference is found as follows

https://semver.org/

So,

> A version number is comprised of one or more identifiers

#### Package managers

Package managers don't universally agree on terminology, but it seems either following semver and using "identifer" or the general term "parts" is the norm.

NPM follows semver and also [uses the term identifer](https://github.com/npm/node-semver/blob/master/internal/identifiers.js).

Golang does the same, though [the code itself](https://github.com/golang/mod/blob/master/semver/semver.go) shortens it to "Ident".

[PIP](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_vendor/packaging/version.py) just calls them *parts*. Perhaps a bit on the nose, but it gets the job done.

Ruby is [the same](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/version.rb) as pip, calling them *parts*.

#### Conclusion

Five years after asking this question, I have found myself referring to them the way I do in the original question: as *segments*.

> A version number is comprised of one or more segments

I think any term that gets across the intent is good enough for the job. I like "segments" since that implies the parts are both contiguous and only a section of the whole.

However, if it important to stay consistent with the semver standard, the term that should be used is *identifier*.

Answer (score 2):

Various version numbering schemes exist, so the meaning and naming of their parts could be different depending on the subject.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning):

> The standard GNU version numbering scheme is major.minor.revision, but emacs is a notable example using another scheme where the major number (1) was dropped and a user site revision was added which is always zero in original emacs packages but increased by distributors. Similarly, Debian package numbers are prefixed with an optional "epoch", which is used to allow the versioning scheme to be changed.

and:

> Other schemes impart meaning on individual sequences:
>
> *major.minor[.build[.revision]]*
>
> or
>
> *major.minor[.maintenance[.build]]*
>
> Again, in these examples, the definition of what constitutes a "major" as opposed to a "minor" change is entirely subjective and up to the author, as is what defines a "build", or how a "revision" differs from a "minor" change.

Answer (score 1):

```
major.minor[.build[.revision]]
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Since the individual parts are normally called major number, minor number, build number and revision number the answer is `numbers`.